# CSS aliasing/inheritance

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to CSS, so this may be obvious or impossible.

I want to define a new CSS class "mytable", which inherits from bootstrap "table-striped table-bordered".

Then in the HTML i can just put

```
<table class="mytable"> etc
```

The reason is that I want to re-use the "mytable" class in lots of places (but not all tables) and if the customer wants to tweak the table format, I can just do it in one place not 20.

How do I do it?

Comment: What does "inherits" means? are you using sass or less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in css, you best bet is using a preprocessor. Bootstrap supports both Less and SASS, I would suggest learning about sass.

Heres some links to get you started.

Getting Started With Sass: Installation And The Basics
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/getting-started-saas/

Using Bootstrap 3 With Sass
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/bootstrap-and-sass/

Answer (score 3):

You could simply copy all the BS table styling into your new mytable class, but it would be better to use multiple classes on your table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered mytable">
```

with the mytable class overriding the properties you want to customise

**Update**
Here's an example of what I'm picturing:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/rHcjv/

It's true that first time through you might have to add the extra class in 20 places. After that can easily update Bootstrap CSS without fear of loosing any customising that you've done and you can update your mytable css in just the one place.

The option of using something like SASS or alternatively LESS as suggested by [James Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1297932/james-campbell) is also really good. If this is new for you then it's a bit more work upfront but you will be well rewarded in the long run

Comment: If I wanted to remove the table-bordered property, I'd have to change it in 20 places, wouldn't I?